Unable to use and extract data from Java Code to EPL using sentEventMap
We are using Esper v8.8.0 and want to use sendEventMap to send a list of objects from Java code to EPL. While we are able to send it using the code below, we are encountering an issue with receiving the data, as we are getting null values.
void sendEventMap(Map<String, Object> event, String eventTypeName);
Schema:
  Event-type name="MyByteEvent"
     java-util-map
            map-property class="byte" name="byteValue" 
     java-util-map
  event-type
  

Java Code:
 Map<String, Object> eventData = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 eventData.put("byteValue", (byte) 2);
 runtime.getEventService().sendEventMap(eventData, "MyByteEvent");

EPL:
@Name('MyByteEventWindow')
@Description('Desc')
create window MyByteWindow.std:unique(byteValue)
(   
    byteValue byte
);

@Name('MyByteEventWindow1')
@Description('Description')
insert into MyByteWindow
select 
    s.byteValue as byteValue
from 
    MyByteEvent as s;


You didn't say where a null shows up
